# Python: saving a joined dataset --- URL path in Cloudera VM

Tags: python, join, text-files, cloudera

I have joined two datasets in Spark (pySpark)and the output looks likes this

```
        (u'SomeThing', (u'ABC', u'500'))
```

I would like to do the following:
Define a function that extracts and returns only ABC, 500. I wrote a function like this

```
           def extract_lasttwo_cols(three_cols):
           a,b,c = three_cols.split(',')
           return b,c
```

But this function results in an error "tuple object has no attribute split()"

So,
I would like to save this joined dataset as a textfile on one of the folders on the HDFS on Cloudera VM. This is a single node VM. I am getting syntax error on this code

```
        joinedatasets.saveAsTextFile("joinSet.txt")
```

I realize that we need to save it to a HDFS URL. My question
How do we find the HDFS url to the file I need to save and is it the appropriate method to save?

Answer (score 0):

Well I just tried the following and it worked, but slightly differently

```
          joinedatasets.saveAsTextFile("input/joinSet")
```

The files that have got saved as five txt files each which are named as

```
                part-00000,
                part-00001 until part-00005
```